# How to get image from an nested input array Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, input

I am trying to get input value in a nested array like the one showed bellow.But the problem is the image array is missing or if not I don't know how to get the value of the image file.

This is how i want

```
 Array
    (
        [_token] => 7iSeeTphiVbpQw3iQ8eb1lReMRzxBY8Lt1lKqQea
        [food] => Array
            (
                [product[1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 1
                        [price] => 10
                        [image]=>Uploaded image here
                    )
            )

    )
```

But what i am actually getting is this

```
Array
(
    [_token] => 7iSeeTphiVbpQw3iQ8eb1lReMRzxBY8Lt1lKqQea
    [food] => Array
        (
            [product[1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1
                    [price] => 10
                )

            [product[2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1
                    [price] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

And my form blade is like this

```
 <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
  <!-----PHP LOOP STARTS HERE ---->
<select class="form-control" name="food[product[$i][name]]">                                                    
  <option value="1">Fried rice</option>
  <option value="2">Demo food</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="set a price" class="form-control" name="food[product[$i][price]]">
<input type="file" placeholder="set a price" class="form-control" name="food[product[$i][image]]">
 <!-----PHP LOOP ENDS HERE ---->
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Can anyone help me how can i get the image so i can store in folder and save the url to database?? In controller

**UPDATE**
I changed the form

```
<input type="text" placeholder="set a price" class="form-control" name="product[$i][price]">
    <input type="file" placeholder="set a price" class="form-control" name="product[$i][image]">
```

In reponse i am getting

```
[product] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1
                    [price] => 10
                    [image] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
                        (
                            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => dell-inspiron-3567-notebook-original-imaetu5ch98vzge5.jpeg
                            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
                            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 40705
                            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                            [hashName:protected] => 
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php17B2.tmp
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php17B2.tmp
                        )

                )
```

After doing that i can see the image is being uploaded. Now how to capture that image ??
If i try foreach loop that image is getting missing. I am getting undefined index for image.
so how shall i proceed ?

Comment: Where's the controller can you show

Comment: as of now controller is nothing but print_r(Input::all());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it can't be done in normal way we do to get image and verified if exist with `Input::hasFile('image') or Input::file('image');`
So this is how i did it.

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=count(Input::get('product'));$i++){
            $data['name']=$request->product[$i]['name'];
            if (isset($request->product[$i]['price']) && !empty($request->product[$i]['price']) && isset($request->product[$i]['image'])){
                $data['price']=$request->product[$i]['price'];

                //upload image
                $name= substr(md5(str_random(10)), 0, 8);
                $imageName = $name.'.'.$request->product[$i]['image']->getClientOriginalExtension();;
                $request->product[$i]['image']->move(public_path('images/food/'), $imageName);
                $data['image']= 'images/product/'.$imageName;
               if (Product::create($data)){
                   $msg ='All product has been successfully uploaded';
               }
            }else{
                $msg ='Opps!! Something went wrong.';
            }
        }
```

I don't know if there is any better way to do so. if so please do let me know.

And thank you @qvotaxon for helping me out and everyone too thanks again :))

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you don't have a file field in your form. If I understand you correctly you want users to be able to upload images. You will need to change the type of the last text input to file.

`<input type="file" placeholder="set a price" class="form-control" name="food[product[$i][image]]">`

And then you can get your image by using $_FILES in your php.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I'm not an expert on Laravel, but could you please try using Input::file and Input::hasFile. As explained here: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files). Using Input::all, as you already used, should probably work. I'm just curious about whether the file is actually being uploaded.

Comment: yes me to wondering if files are actually been uploaded or not.
Since its a nested array the way i think i can try to getting image is through looping. But in loop cant use File or hasFile,
and if i try to do`Input::hasFile(); or Input::file(); `it returns nothing blank

Comment: Have you looked through your apache and php error log? Maybe something is going wrong with the file upload. E.g file is to large or something like that.

Comment: Yes,  nothing is there.
Btw i changed the input form little bit and now i can see in the response that the image is being uploaded. Now the only problem  remaining is how to capture that image

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually the problem, but the documentation states that you need to run the command `Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath);` or `Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` to move the actual file to a directory (saving the file).

In your case I think it should be (if in loop): `Input::file($nameOfArray['product'][$i]['image'])->move($destinationPath);`

Or

`Input::file($nameOfArray['product'][1]['image'])->move($destinationPath);`
If not in a loop.

_On a side note: Actually it's kinda strange the array starts at index 1 :P_

Comment: Lol yeah, strange array it is . And yeah i thinks that's the only way i guess of getting data i guess.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't be of more help. Hope this solves your issue. Have a nice day!